# Promote a widget by the code

Tags: qt, user-interface

I would like to know how to promote a widget in another by the code. I know it is possible using the Designer but I want the widget to be dynamic, so I have to change it in the code.

Answer (score 5):

Delete the old widget, then create the new widget and place it where the old one was.

You cannot keep the old object and just change its class.

Comment: Vote up. The qt-creator does nothing else, it only displays a known generic class as placeholder, but in generated code this will still be a: myWidget = new myWidgetClass();